# Convert a list to data.frame with multiple columns in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a list that looks like this

```
[[1]]
1 2
[[2]]
10 20 30 
[[3]]
4
```

and I would like to convert it to a dataframe that looks like this

```
column1 column2 column3
   1       2      NA
   10      20     30
   4       NA      NA
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to get the `lengths` of the `list` elements, get the `max` length, pad NA at the end where the length is less than the `max` length and `dbind` the `list` elements

```
mx <- max(lengths(lst1))
out <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(lst1, `length<-`, mx))
names(out) <- paste0('column', 1:3)
out
#  column1 column2 column3
#1       1       2      NA
#2      10      20      30
#3       4      NA      NA
```

#### data

```
lst1 <- list(1:2, c(10, 20, 30), 4)
```

Comment: That looks pretty neat @akrun thank you. I 'll try to adjust it to my data.frame and I ll add thumps up to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Another option, with the data introduced as by @akrun answer, would be:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
lst1 %>%
    map_dfr(~as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(.)))) %>%
    rename_with(~sub("V", "column",.))
```

It would also work using `unlist` or `as.numeric` instead of `as.matrix`.

Comment: That's a pretty neat solution @iago. I really like it. It works perfectly for the lst1 but unfortunately, in my long list I am taking this error "Error: Argument 1 must have names.". What troubles me is that I don't understand which one should have names. Thank you for your answer

Comment: I should look at such list. You may try to debug the error with `traceback()`